# Possible to enable diagnostic settings when creating an Azure VM via CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I haven't found a command line switch for enabling diagnostic settings when creating a VM with the Azure CLI.

I know it works in the portal, but likely this is a separate step in the deployment template.

However, there is a new command line switch for enabling log analytics workspace immediately (Preview).

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I think you are right, there is currently not a way to do this directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[az vm create cli](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create) does not provide the arguments about diagnostic settings, so I am afraid that we cannot enable diagnostic settings when creating an azure vm.

As workaround, you can try to enable the diagnostics settings using Azure CLI by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/diagnostics?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-diagnostics-set).

```
az vm diagnostics set --settings
                      [--ids]
                      [--no-auto-upgrade {false, true}]
                      [--protected-settings]
                      [--resource-group]
                      [--subscription]
                      [--version]
                      [--vm-name]
```

Here is a [case](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8108) on github you can refer to .